# Using this dupe finding query to get all results of 2 records entered for a client in another table

Tags: sql

I can get the exact duplicates with this query but is there a way to tweak this so that I can get the rows that have the same last name, first name and id but the race info, is different > that means they entered 2 race records for the same person. The query gives me the people they entered the same race info twice.

```
select ra.people_id, ra.race_info_id, ac.last_name, ac.first_name, ac.id_no, count( ) from race ra join all_clients_view ac on ra.people_id = ac.people_id group by ra.people_id, ra.race_info_id, ac.last_name, ac.first_name, ac.id_no having count( )
```

1 this gives only the exact matches. I have some cases where the race is entered twice for a client. Not exact match. I have to locate those as well. For bi-racial we have a value for bi-racial but some enter 2 anyway. I need to locate the race where it's not exactly the same

Answer (score 0):

Removing `ra.race_info_id` from the `GROUP BY` clause should help. Then the tuples will be grouped only on `ra.people_id, ac.last_name, ac.first_name, ac.id_no` and result in rows with different `ra.race_info_id`.

```
SELECT ra.people_id, ra.race_info_id, ac.last_name, ac.first_name, ac.id_no, count( ) 
FROM race ra
JOIN all_clients_view ac ON ra.people_id = ac.people_id
GROUP BY ra.people_id ac.last_name, ac.first_name, ac.id_no 
HAVING count( )
```

Comment: HI I tried this but it won't accept Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Column 'race.race_info_id' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Completion time: 2022-08-21T08:53:51.6940713-04:00

Comment: If it's still unresolved, kindly include the schema for the related tables for more context on the problem.